# Way to turn invalid Json to valid

Tags: java, json

I am working on a project with a SonicWall router. The responses that I get from it are in json format. I have no problems parsing them etc, etc but it seems that there is one case where the SW will return an invalid json as a response. Here is an example:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "reboot_required": false,
    "status": [
        {
            "cli": [
                { "command": [ { "token": "no" }, { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "id", "error": true }, { "token": "10", "error": true } ] },
                { "command": [ { "token": "end" } ] }
            ],
            "info": [
                 { "type": "error", "code": "CLI_E_NOT_FOUND", "message": "Nat Policy not found.
" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the message does not close properly but changes a line? This causes the following parsingException:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Unexpected char 13 at (line no=11, column no=97, offset=447)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.unexpectedChar(JsonTokenizer.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.readString(JsonTokenizer.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonTokenizer.nextToken(JsonTokenizer.java:376)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$ObjectContext.getNextEvent(JsonParserImpl.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readArray(JsonReaderImpl.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readArray(JsonReaderImpl.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:103)
```

Is there any way to turn this in a valid json?

Comment: how are you parsing the json? What API are you using?

Comment: Your "`"Nat Policy not found` is not ending with double quotes, so you need to update it to end with ".

Answer (score 3):

Get the json response and replace all new lines first before parsing it to object.

```
response.replaceAll("\r?\n", "");
```

Sample code using `GSON` API

```
    String json = "{\"msg\" : \"Hello \n World\"}";
    System.out.println(json);

    json = json.replaceAll("\r?\n", "");

    Map<String, String> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println("Actual message:" + map.get("msg"));
```

Output:

```
{"msg" : " Hello 
 World"}
Actual message: Hello  World
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it might be neater to replace with something like "\\n" instead: that way, you'll keep the newlines.